# Why spring-boot-actuator code uses filters to capture metrics rather than interceptors?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a use case at my work which is similar to what `spring-boot-actuator` provides.

Spring Boot Actuator uses [MetricsFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricsFilter.java) to capture the metrics/counters on incoming requests. My question is why filters were chosen for metrics aggregation and not interceptors. While thinking on it, I can see the same implementation could be done at interceptor level. Since I have followed filter approach, my colleagues are questioning me why I did not go with interceptor level. I don't have any strong points to convince them that one is better than other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actuator's metrics are designed to work with any web framework. An Interecptor is Spring MVC specific, whereas a Filter will work with any HTTP request that's received.